# Split Big String by Specific Word In Python

Tags: python, split

I want to split a big string by word and that word is repeating in that big string.

> Example what i expect :
>   [image: What I expect]

We have tried to split a code, please check below

`string.split("RFF+AAJ:")`

So we need a bunch of list that i have described in my above screenshot.

Comment: please share what result you have got  from that code and also paste your data here and foramt using Code formatter

Comment: you are doing it correctly. I think it should work

Comment: would expect that string "REF+AAJ:" also include that list

Comment: Where would `REF+AAJ` be in the list? In the earlier or later element? It usually helps a lot to share your expected outputs with us.

Comment: I agreed with above all your comments there would be a 3 list but we are splitting here by "REE+AAJ:" word so actually that word will be not there obviously :) and i want to display also into that list.

Comment: It's currently unclear what you want. Please outline your expected outputs as code. E.g. `["first_part", "second_part", "third_part"]`. Until you do that, it's extremely difficult to help.

Comment: Can't you just add back `REF+AAJ` from the 2nd item on your list onwards?

Comment: @HenryYik yes i think we can skip first one list then we add manually this word to all other list,

Comment: @byxor as i said , we can do manually add this word to all other list , instead of first one.

Comment: It looks like you know how to solve it. Good luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get your result with the help of `regex` :-

```
import re
string = 'helloisworldisbyeishi'
re.split('(is)', string)  # Splitting from 'is'
```

**Output**

```
['hello', 'is', 'world', 'is', 'bye', 'is', 'hi']
```

I hope it may help you.

Answer (score 1):

`split` returns one single list with the complete string in it ( it is just split in parts ). So the list here contains the part before the first `"RFF+AAJ:"`, then the part between the two `"RFF+AAJ:"`s and the last part, after the second `"RFF+AAJ:"`. If you want to have three differrent lists use:

```
all = string.split("RFF+AAJ:")
first = all[0]
second = all[1]
third = all[2]
```

And the elements will be stored in first, second and third. 
If you want to create lists, use `first = list(first) # and so on`.
Hope that helped.

Comment: Thank you guys for help , acutally we add manually that word to all strings expect first one ! so it will also resolve it